# Partial Differentiation in Mathematica, syntax error?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerics, syntax, differentials

I am trying to differentiate some random function using Mathematica at particular nodes, I am though not being able to implement this without being retrieved the following error message:

> D: Multiple variable specifier {-1, -1.25, -1.5, -1.75, -2, -2.25, -2.5, -2.75, -3} does not have the form {variable, n} where n is symbolic or non-negative integer

The code I have is:

```
f[x_] := Cos[3 x]
a = -1.0; b = 1.0; nodes = 8;
xvec = Table[a + (i (a - b))/nodes, {i, 0, nodes}];
fprime[x_] :=  D[f[x], x]//N
f[xvec]; fprime[xvec]
ListPlot[{xvec, fprime[xvec]}]
```

I have also tried

```
fprime[x_] := Table [\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\(f[x]\)\) /. {x -> nodes[[i]]} {i,
      0, nodes}]
```

Not sure what is going wrong given I can do the following:

```
ff[xx_] := Cos[3 xx] // N
ffprime[xx_] = D[f[xx], xx] // N;
xxvec = {-1, 0, 2, 4}
yyvec = ff[xxvec]
ffprime[xxvec]
```

It works and accepts n as negative integer. New to mathematica is there anything basic that I am missing ?

Any hints/comments are welcomed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to evaluate the derivative before using it otherwise the derivative is taken with respect to a constant - x.

```
f[x_] := Cos[3 x]
a = -1.0; b = 1.0; nodes = 8;
xvec = Table[a + (i (a - b))/nodes, {i, 0, nodes}];
fprime[x_] := Evaluate@D[f[x], x]
f[xvec]; fprime[xvec]
ListPlot[{xvec, fprime[xvec]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Say we wanted to defined a new function using Module and we want to use the derivative function, is there a way we could use it in our definition for  the function  until we call it later on or we can use `Evaluate@` ? as well inside the definition ?

Comment: You are welcome. `Module` is a scoping construct so it should not matter. e.g. if you use `f[x_] := Module[{}, Cos[3 x]]` then the above code will work fine. But maybe I am misunderstanding your question. BTW would you mind upvoting my answer. Thanks.